# Convention for Database Creation

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

We're developing a new product at work and it will require the use of a lightweight database.  My coworkers and I, however, got into a debate over the conventions for database creation.  They were of the mindset that we should just build quick outline of the database and go in and indiscriminately add and delete tables and stuff until it looks like what we want.  I told them the proper way to do it was to make a script that follows a format similar to this:

Drop database;

Create Tables;

Insert Initial Data;

I said this was better than randomly changing tables.   You should only make changes to the script and re-run the script every time you want to update the design of the database.  They said it was pointless and that their way was faster (which holds a bit of weight since the database is kind of small, but I still feel it is a bad way of doing things).  Their BIGGEST concern with this was that I was dropping the database, they were upset that I was going to delete the random data they put in there for testing purposes.  That's when I clarified that you include inserts as part of the script that will act as initial data.  They were still unconvinced.  They told me in all of their time with databases they had NEVER heard of such a thing.  The truth is we all need more experience with databases, but I am CERTAIN that this is the proper way to develop a script and create a database.  Does anyone have any online resources that clearly explain this method that can back me up?  If I am wrong about this, then please fell free to correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know the details of your project, but I think its pretty safe to assume you're right on this one, for a number of very good reasons.

1. If you don't have a script that dictates how the database is structured, how will create new instances of it? What happens when you deploy to production or it gets accidentally deleted or the server crashes? Having a script means you don't have to remember all the little details of how it was all set up (which is pretty unlikely even for small databases).
2. It's way faster in the long run. I don't know about you, but in my projects I'm constantly bringing new databases online for things like unit testing, new branches, and deployments. If I had to recreate the database from by hand every time it would take forever. Yes it takes a *little* extra time to maintain a database script but it will almost always save you time over the life of the project.
3. It's not hard to do. I don't know what database you're using but many of them support exporting your schema as a DDL script. You can just start with that and modify it from them on. No need to type it all up. If your database won't do that, it's worth a quick search to see if a 3rd party tool that works with your database will do it for you.

Make sure your check your scripts into your source control system. It's just as important as any other part of your source code.

I think having a data seeding script like you mentioned is a good idea. But keep it as a separate script from the database creation script. This way your can a developer seed script, a unit testing seed script, a production seed script, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  We're using a java library called H2, which is what we're limited to.  We're working on a closed network that does not have internet access so we can't download anything.  Any new software we put on needs approvals and signatures (which can take months).  So we're basically stuck with what we have.  So right now we're limited to typing everything out.  What we have doesn't have any tools except for the ones we build ourselves.  I've googled searched for database creation conventions, but most sites and videos have tools that do it automatically.  Again, thank you.

Comment: Got it. interesting environment you're working in. I'd still recommend going with the scripts even if you have to type them out. Once you get the syntax down it shouldn't be too bad.